# How to obtain exception / failure message from Protractor /Cucumber in an After hook

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am trying to find a way to get exception details in an after hook for a Protractor / Cucumber framework I have setup so I am able to log the failure reasons in a report.

I have read both the Protractor and Cucumber.js documentation and cannot find any clear way of achieving this. Wondered if someone had an idea?

Ideally, I'd like to obtain it during an after hook stage such as onCleapUp() or in a cucumber After() stage once the test(s) have completed.

Comment: Looks like you can create a [custom formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/custom_formatters.md) and get access to the test results using [EventDataCollector](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/76d50cd5e613be5ed7897e44fdb493c52d324f32/src/formatter/helpers/event_data_collector.js#L11). I'm not familiar with Cucumber so I can't say if the stacktrace is actually in there but have a look and see if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a code example?